# Division between two dataframes using column value

Tags: python, pandas

{In [16]: print(data_15)

```
           ene2015  feb2015  mar2015  abr2015  may2015  jun2015  ...  c12015  c22015  c32015  s12015  s22015    a2015
statename                                                        ...
Nacional      38.0     32.0     45.0     49.0     35.0     36.0  ...   164.0   131.0   120.0   235.0   180.0    415.0
Nacional     679.0    702.0    684.0    734.0    816.0    752.0  ...  2799.0  3189.0  3222.0  4367.0  4843.0   9210.0
Nacional      89.0    108.0     76.0     85.0     96.0    107.0  ...   358.0   346.0   357.0   561.0   500.0   1061.0
Nacional    1197.0   1218.0   1235.0   1297.0   1410.0   1361.0  ...  4947.0  5648.0  5526.0  7718.0  8403.0  16121.0
Nacional    1229.0   1248.0   1266.0   1332.0   1438.0   1388.0  ...  5075.0  5775.0  5682.0  7901.0  8631.0  16532.0
...            ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...      ...
Zacatecas     22.0     18.0     20.0     17.0     11.0     20.0  ...    77.0    70.0    85.0   108.0   124.0    232.0
Zacatecas      9.0     13.0     16.0     10.0      6.0     14.0  ...    48.0    47.0    64.0    68.0    91.0    159.0
Zacatecas   1261.0   1330.0   1409.0   1325.0   1398.0   1469.0  ...  5325.0  5584.0  5270.0  8192.0  7987.0  16179.0
Zacatecas     36.0     61.0     52.0     70.0     71.0     78.0  ...   219.0   250.0   266.0   368.0   367.0    735.0
Zacatecas      4.0      2.0      8.0      5.0      4.0      5.0  ...    19.0    24.0    10.0    28.0    25.0     53.0
```

[759 rows x 22 columns]

In [17]: print(pob_15)

```
                                        2015
statename
Aguascalientes                     1287660.0
Baja California                    3484150.0
Baja California Sur                 763929.0
Campeche                            907878.0
Chiapas                            5252808.0
Chihuahua                          3710129.0
Coahuila de Zaragoza               2960681.0
Colima                              723455.0
Ciudad de México                   8854600.0
Durango                            1764726.0
Guanajuato                         5817614.0
Guerrero                           3568139.0
Hidalgo                            2878369.0
Jalisco                            7931267.0
Michoacán de Ocampo                4596499.0
Morelos                            1920350.0
México                            16870388.0
Nacional                         121005816.0
Nayarit                            1223797.0
Nuevo León                         5085848.0
Oaxaca                             4012295.0
Puebla                             6193836.0
Querétaro                          2004472.0
Quintana Roo                       1574824.0
San Luis Potosí                    2753478.0
Sinaloa                            2984571.0
Sonora                             2932821.0
Tabasco                            2383900.0
Tamaulipas                         3543366.0
Tlaxcala                           1278308.0
Veracruz de Ignacio de la Llave    8046828.0
Yucatán                            2118762.0
Zacatecas                          1576068.0
```

In [18]: data_15/pob_15
Out[18]:

```
                2015  a2015  abr2015  ago2015  c12015  c22015  ...  s22015  sep2015  t12015  t22015  t32015  t42015
statename                                                      ...
Aguascalientes   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Aguascalientes   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Aguascalientes   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Aguascalientes   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Aguascalientes   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
...              ...    ...      ...      ...     ...     ...  ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
Zacatecas        NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Zacatecas        NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Zacatecas        NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Zacatecas        NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
Zacatecas        NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

}

Comment: Please don't post images. `print(dataframe)` is better.

Comment: @AngelSerrano can this question be closed?

Comment: @Kenan sorry, i ddnt mean that i've solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add `pob_15` and then divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with `axis=0` parameter by original `data_15`:

```
df = data_15.div(data_15.join(pob_15)[2015], axis=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
                ene2015       feb2015       mar2015       abr2015  \
statename                                                           
Nacional   3.140345e-07  2.644501e-07  3.718830e-07  4.049392e-07   
Nacional   5.611301e-06  5.801374e-06  5.652621e-06  6.065824e-06   
Nacional   7.355018e-07  8.925191e-07  6.280690e-07  7.024456e-07   
Nacional   9.892087e-06  1.006563e-05  1.020612e-05  1.071849e-05   
Nacional   1.015654e-05  1.031355e-05  1.046231e-05  1.100774e-05   
Zacatecas  1.395879e-05  1.142083e-05  1.268981e-05  1.078634e-05   
Zacatecas  5.710414e-06  8.248375e-06  1.015185e-05  6.344904e-06   
Zacatecas  8.000924e-04  8.438722e-04  8.939970e-04  8.406998e-04   
Zacatecas  2.284165e-05  3.870391e-05  3.299350e-05  4.441433e-05   
Zacatecas  2.537962e-06  1.268981e-06  5.075923e-06  3.172452e-06   

                may2015       jun2015    c12015    c22015        c32015  \
statename                                                                 
Nacional   2.892423e-07  2.975064e-07  0.000001  0.000001  9.916879e-07   
Nacional   6.743478e-06  6.214577e-06  0.000023  0.000026  2.662682e-05   
Nacional   7.933503e-07  8.842550e-07  0.000003  0.000003  2.950271e-06   
Nacional   1.165233e-05  1.124739e-05  0.000041  0.000047  4.566723e-05   
Nacional   1.188373e-05  1.147052e-05  0.000042  0.000048  4.695642e-05   
Zacatecas  6.979394e-06  1.268981e-05  0.000049  0.000044  5.393168e-05   
Zacatecas  3.806942e-06  8.882865e-06  0.000030  0.000030  4.060738e-05   
Zacatecas  8.870176e-04  9.320664e-04  0.003379  0.003543  3.343764e-03   
Zacatecas  4.504882e-05  4.949025e-05  0.000139  0.000159  1.687744e-04   
Zacatecas  2.537962e-06  3.172452e-06  0.000012  0.000015  6.344904e-06   

             s12015    s22015     a2015  
statename                                
Nacional   0.000002  0.000001  0.000003  
Nacional   0.000036  0.000040  0.000076  
Nacional   0.000005  0.000004  0.000009  
Nacional   0.000064  0.000069  0.000133  
Nacional   0.000065  0.000071  0.000137  
Zacatecas  0.000069  0.000079  0.000147  
Zacatecas  0.000043  0.000058  0.000101  
Zacatecas  0.005198  0.005068  0.010265  
Zacatecas  0.000233  0.000233  0.000466  
Zacatecas  0.000018  0.000016  0.000034
```